# Angular generates 'Error: No provider for AngularFirestore!' with Cloud Firestore

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I cannot run the code provided in this tutorial:
https://coursetro.com/posts/code/94/Use-Angular-with-Google's-Cloud-Firestore---Tutorial

I am getting an error in the console

After installing the new library

npm install angularfire2 firebase --save

and running

ng serve

I also got the latest cli

I am getting this error in the console:

```
ERROR Error: No provider for AngularFirestore!
at injectionError (vendor.bundle.js:87513)
at noProviderError (vendor.bundle.js:87551)
at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (vendor.bundle.js:88993)
at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (vendor.bundle.js:89032)
at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (vendor.bundle.js:88964)
at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.get (vendor.bundle.js:88833)
at resolveNgModuleDep (vendor.bundle.js:95836)
at NgModuleRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.NgModuleRef_.get (vendor.bundle.js:96906)
at resolveDep (vendor.bundle.js:97394)
at createClass (vendor.bundle.js:97256)
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';


export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "val",
  authDomain: "val",
  databaseURL: "val",
  projectId: "val",
  storageBucket: "val",
  messagingSenderId: "val"
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
interface Post {
  title: string;
  content: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  postsCol: AngularFirestoreCollection<Post>;
  posts: Observable<Post[]>;
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.postsCol = this.afs.collection('posts');
    this.posts = this.postsCol.valueChanges();
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<ul *ngFor="let post of posts | async">
  <li>
    <strong>{{ post.title}}</strong>
    <br>
    {{post.content}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 11):

You should add `providers: [AngularFirestore]` in `app.module.ts`.

Because You should notice to angular this module has injection.

like this.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [AngularFirestore],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: import the following in app.module.ts in addition:  import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
 import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

Comment: I cannot imagine why this would be necessary. Certainly `AngularFirestoreModule` itself declares `AngularFirestore` as a provider, so that just importing it should be enough.

Comment: Just throws an error again with the message Cannot find name 'AngularFirestore'.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

> I only imported  **AngularFirestoreModule** in my app.module.ts
>   'imports array' without importing **AngularFireStore** in providers.

Answer (score 1):

I added the provider entry, 
providers: [AngularFirestore],
and import.
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
Received this error:

> Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AngularFirestore: ([object Object], ?).
>       at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1694)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15781)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15649)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15635)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15926)
>       at compiler.es5.js:15855
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15815)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15470)
>       at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.es5.js:26826)
>
> ---
>
> I reverted the change to the original app.module.ts. Same code from the tutorial just worked the next day. No Dependency Injection complaints. Data loaded from the database

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same errors. I had to remove AngularFirestoreModule from my imports in my app.module.ts, without adding it to providers. This might be because I was already importing it as part of a CoreModule I'd set up.

Comment: I just added it to the `Providers` section of `app.module` and the error was gone. I also have the same `imports` as the OP. I'm following the setup guide here https://github.com/angular/angularfire2