# Angular 13 NullInjectorError: No provider for AngularFirestoreCollection

Tags: angular, firebase

I am working on my personal project in Angular and currently, my Angular CLI is "~13.3.0" "firebase": "^9.5.0" "@angular/fire": "^7.3.0". I am trying to get all documents from firebase using AngularFirestoreCollection. The problem is, I am getting this error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[Services -> AngularFirestoreCollection -> AngularFirestoreCollection -> AngularFirestoreCollection]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for AngularFirestoreCollection!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[Services -> AngularFirestoreCollection -> AngularFirestoreCollection -> AngularFirestoreCollection]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for AngularFirestoreCollection!
```

How can I fix this problem?

**service.ts**

```
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 
'@angular/fire/compat/firestore';

constructor(
   public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
   private afs: AngularFirestore,
   private itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>
) { }

getCollectionURL(filter: string) {
   return 'ecomm/shopp/products/category/'+filter;
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { initializeApp,provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { provideAuth,getAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { provideDatabase,getDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { provideFirestore,getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { provideStorage,getStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreModule } from "@angular/fire/compat/firestore/";

imports: 
        [
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase, 'ecomm'),
        AngularFirestoreModule,
        AngularFireAuthModule,
        AngularFireDatabaseModule,
        provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
        provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
        provideDatabase(() => getDatabase()),
        provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
        provideStorage(() => getStorage())
       ]

providers: [
        {
        provide: MatDialogRef,
        useValue: {}
        },
        EventEmitterService,
        AngularFirestore
        ],
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular generates 'Error: No provider for AngularFirestore!' with Cloud Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46881410/angular-generates-error-no-provider-for-angularfirestore-with-cloud-firestor)

Comment: @Guillaume So weird because based on your suggested answer, I have already done that and still getting the error No provider for AngularFirestoreCollection.

Comment: No you did not. You need to add ''AngularFirestore'' in your providers array. Read the answer completly.

Comment: Okay, I have updated my question to make it clear. As I have already said, I have already done that yesterday. I have AngularFirestore in my providers array but I am getting same error. I duplicated my package.json and package-lock.json and deleted the node_modules folder and reinstall but still the same. Does the angular cli version matters with this? Because in "@angular/cli": "~11.0.2" it works well

Comment: why are you using both the modular and namespaced imports of Firebase? Have you tried using only one? (v9 preferable, that is provideStuff pattern)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments. Unfortunately, none of the above mentions works for me. I ended up moving itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any> out of the constructor and it works as expected.

    itemsCollection!: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>
      constructor(
       public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
        private afs: AngularFirestore,
        // public itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>
      ) {  }